# I cant Install NvChad ( linux ). init.lua is not detected by neovim

Tags: neovim

I'm trying to install NcChad on neovim with the following command:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad ~/.config/nvim --depth 1 && nvim
```

It doesn't work. I think it's because neovim can't find the `init.lua` file. When I rename this file to `init.vim` and enter neovim, it finds the file and gives an error.

Why can't neovim find `init.lua`?

Comment: To confirm your suspicion that it can't find the init.lua you could try specifying the config file `nvim -u ~/.config/nvim/init.lua`. If it still fails you could add the given errors to your question. Errors should be in `~/.cache/nvim/`

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by removing everything that was previously installed on my system.

First make sure you have installed a [NeoVim version](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases) greater than 8.3 (minimum required for NvChad according to its [install page](https://nvchad.com/docs/quickstart/install))

```
nvim --version
```

[image]

backup your current config with:

```
mv -r ~/.config/nvim ~/.config/NVIM_BACKUP
```

then:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/nvim
rm -rf ~/.local/share/nvim
git clone https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad ~/.config/nvim --depth 1 && nvim
```

#### Hope it helps!

Comment: removing ~/.local/share/nvim helped! Thanks a lot!